# Manipulation of eit by calling isDebuggerPresent

Tags: debugging, assembly, malware, ollydbg, malware-detection

Found a nice code snippet (https://github.com/invictus1306/Anti-debugging-techniques/blob/master/anti-debugging.asm) for anti-debugging mechanism in asm. 
My question is about following snippet:

```
 ;IsDebuggerPresent first - kernel32!IsDebuggerPresent
    call IsDebuggerPresent
    call @eip_manipulate ; change eip (point to next instruction)
    mov eax, 010h
    cmp eax, 1
    je @Detected

  [...]

      @eip_manipulate:
    add dword ptr [esp], 5
    ret
```

I don't get why I have to change this. Because if i call isDebuggerPresent, it will return 1 for debuggerIsPresent or a 0 for debuggerIsNotPresent. 
Tried this and it only works with the eip_manipulate call.

Comment: I think the idea is that a debugger stepping *over* functions might set a breakpoint after the `call`, which would never be hit because `@eip_manipulate` doesn't return to the normal return-address.  IDK if it's helpful for anything other than a minor trick against interactive debugging, though.

Comment: Obviously if you don't skip the `mov eax, 010h` (5 bytes long), then it will overwrite EAX so the `cmp` is always false, so you can't just remove the `call @eip_manipulate`

Comment: @Peter Cordes so i tried this now without calling *@eip_manipulate* and without *mov eax, 010 h* and it works fine with OllyDbg. As you said, this was obvious. Anyhow, thanks for your help.